# Android + Facebook SSO

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, single-sign-on

I have a small Android app with Facebook login and I also have the Facebook app installed on my phone. The code for Facebook login is as follows:

```
    if(access_token != null && access_token != "")
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

    if(expires != 0)
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);

    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) 
    {
        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "publish_checkins", "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener() 
        {
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
            {
                /*
                if (GlobalData.user != null)
                {
                    GlobalData.user.fbToken = facebook.getAccessToken();
                    GlobalData.user.fbTokenExpires = facebook.getAccessExpires();
                    dataSource.addUser(GlobalData.user);
                }
                else */

                gatherFacebookData();
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            public void onError(DialogError e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            public void onCancel() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    else
        this.gatherFacebookData();
```

Before the Facebook app was installed I could use Facebook SSO inside my app without any problem. However, now I click on the "Login with Facebook" button, a popup window flashes with a loading screen and disappears immediately. None of the DialogListener functions is called and so I have no idea what happens. Logcat doesn't show any error at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: From the description that you gave I think you are logged in in your facebook app, and hence, when you click on the Login with facebook link, it signs 'you' in and hence the dialog disappears.

Comment: I thought the same, but where does it return the authentication credentials to? As far as I can tell, I'm not receiving that data anywhere...

Comment: That is the whole SSO concept. You are logged in in the FB app. The credentials come from there. Since your app has a reference to your profile, it logs in to your profile.

Comment: Yes, I understand that... But I somehow need to get the access token to check if the session is valid and be able to store it somewhere so that I can use it in my app, right?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code
            facebook.authorize(this, permissions, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());

Answer (score 0):

To store the access_token, add the following code snippet to your `onComplete` method (I'm not sure what your `gatherFacebookData()` method is since you didn't include it.

```
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
            }
```

As you can see, you store the user's access_token into SharedPreferences, so that in your `onCreate` method **before** you check `if (!facebook.isSessionValid())`, you do the following:

```
    /*
     * Get existing access_token if any
     */
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if(access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. While my code seems to work, the facebook window that pops up is slightly annoying. Is there any way to suppress that window, or is it a byproduct of SSO? from a design point of view, it seems as if this would be distracting to the end user.